# This python works, but looking for a more elegant solution (Try and Catch with 1/0 hack)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to prevent user from entering a number of team members that exceeds the player pool.

```
while True:
    try:
        numMembers = int(input("How many students per team (2, or 3) "))
        if numMembers > totalStudents:
            errorHand = 1/0
    except:
        print("Too many members per team, please try again")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Just trying to avoid the hackity div/0 trick I came up with.

Comment: Try to format your answer please

Comment: Your error handling is to divide by zero...?  :)

Comment: This is almost creative

Comment: It's a good workaround for Python lack of a GOTO actually

Comment: Take a look at [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658).

Comment: Is `if numMembers > totalStudents: print('Too many members') else: break` not good enough?

Comment: Downvoters/closevoters, why?  Upvoted because this is an answerable and reasonable question.

Comment: Please try to come up with a more descriptive title for your question. One that gives the reader an idea of what the question is about.

Comment: TBH, I have seen worse things in production systems written by people paid for that.

Comment: @bereal not equivalent because the `except` will also catch `ValueError` for invalid literals passed like `int('a')`

Comment: @Chris_Rands fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to do something different in each error case, there isn’t much complexity that can be taken out, but you can reduce the `try` to a specific exception in a specific place and avoid the division by zero hack:

```
while True:
    try:
        numMembers = int(input("How many students per team (2, or 3) "))
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if numMembers > totalStudents:
        print("Too many members per team, please try again")
        continue

    break
```

Comment: That saves me one line, prevents the unsightly div/0, and adds varType validation. Thank you!!